# Split a jupyter cell into multiple slides

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using a jupyter notebook as a sandbox for my tests. I like it because it's easy to just generate slides to show some plots when discussing the results via Zoom. However, I have a minor issue.

I wrote a function that grabs several columns of my dataset, perform some calculations with them, and then plot all the possible combinations of one column vs. the other. I want them to be visible full size, not micro, like in a `pandas.scatter_matrix` plot. But the results are way too big to fit in a single slide. Is there any way to split it? For the moment, I activated the scrollbar and I can scroll down the slide, but is ugly (I use Reveal)

`jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve  --SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True`

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

from itertools import combinations

fruit_data = np.random.randn(500,5)
fruit_names = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Mangoes', 'Kiwis']

def plot_data(data, labels):
    n_series = data.shape[1]
    plot_index = list(combinations(np.arange(n_series), 2))
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5*len(plot_index)))
    for i,plot in enumerate(plot_index):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(len(plot_index), 1, i+1)
        ax.scatter(data[:, plot[0]], data[:, plot[1]])
        # Get axis labels
        ax.set_xlabel(labels[plot[0]])
        ax.set_ylabel(labels[plot[1]])

plot_data(fruit_data, fruit_names)
```

The output is like this. The real case has more features in the data, several series, with different colors, trends, etc.

[image]

Comment: Instead of subplots you can plot them separately so they won't be a single loooooong figure, or plot them with two columns

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to populate other cells programatically.  However, if you restructure your plot_data script to just do a few at a time, you can just do `plot_data(group1)` in the first cell, `plot_data(group2)` in the second, etc.

Comment: Thanks @JodyKlymak. I was doing so, but it was tedious, so I put everything in the function. I'm not sure if matplotlibs have other structure besides subplots that allows me to plot programmatically. In any case, I guess that what works in a notebook is not always the best for a slideshow

Comment: I mean Matplotlib can do whatever you want, its jupyter that wants to assign each cell to a slide that is the limiting factor.